# socket asynchronous program in pure c language

Tags: c, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

While I was doing practice for async sockets programming.

As per my understanding select() call is blocking and not an async.

I want to write a program in which if I call a function say **emit_event(some_fd_set, call_back_function_ptr)**. this function should not block and the program should continue executions. and whenever an thing gets available on the **some_fd_set** then call_back_function_ptr should gets called.

How to achieve this functionality using pure C programming. ( No boost and C++ )

Thanks

Comment: `select` call is not blocking if you specify timeout equal to zero.

Comment: Well, run the select() call on another thread and callback when something interesting happens, ie. select() returns.   There you go - async.

Comment: Thanks, Any simple example will really help me much.

Comment: I too would like to see a simple example.